# What could be causing multiple computers in an office to restart?

Tags: hardware-failure, reboot, physical-environment

Two months ago, one of the computers in our office began to restart randomly. The restarts didn't seem to follow any pattern - the CPU temperature never fluctuated and it happened both when idle and under strain. We wrote it off as faulty and sent it back to the manufacturer for repair (we're yet to hear back from them on a cause).

Since then, two more computers have started doing the same thing, with one eventually refusing to power on at all.

- All three computers are different builds from different manufacturers
- Two run Windows 7, one runs Windows 8
- All computers run ESET antivirus and all are reported as clean
- Two of the computers have been in the same physical office location, in case that helps

Is this just a coincidence, or could there be an underlying environmental cause?

Comment: I suppose it could be the electricity supply, but it doesn't seem likely.   Have there been any other electrical weird things happening? New additional load on the supply/

Comment: @Paul Not to my knowledge - we've not had any new equipment and everything else appears to be functioning normally.

Answer (score 1):

The computers could be experiencing a blue screen of death (BSOD). Because Windows 7 and 8 have been configured by default to restart automatically then if you hadn't been at the machine during the restart then you would have missed the BSOD (I couldn't tell from your excerpt if you were absent during the restarts but I'll assume so for now).

You can disable the automatic restart on system failure so that when there is BSOD then you would be able to see it upon your return to the machine. This link describes how to do this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2621246. In essence, you would rick-click on My Computer and then properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> Startup and recovery settings button -> Uncheck Automatic restart. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the process I followed in the end - turns out it may have been caused by a GeForce driver, so I guess the answer to my question is "Coincidence" thankfully.